# Shall we keep shelling out questions for [shell]?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

We have a [shell](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shell) tag, but we also have more specific shell tags such as [sh](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sh) and [bash](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bash). Many tags with [shell](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shell) also include these specific tags, so it almost looks redundant. I could see that there are other questions without specific tags, and I assume they would still need this tag. Should we still do something about it to help prevent it from being "sprinkled" over different questions that don't really need it specifically?

Answer (score 2):

I think this tag has a value. It can help users proficient in shell-scripting (in all its forms) to find questions that are doing shell scripting.

There's some common standard errors in shellscripts that are applicable across all (or at least a large number of) shell specializations.

In that sense this tag is a convenience "category" for users to not have to follow [sh](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sh) [bash](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bash) [zsh](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zsh) [ksh](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ksh) [tcsh](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tcsh) ... and still be able to find questions they can (and want to) answer